# structure containing character array as its member in C linux

Tags: c, linux, struct

I know it's a simple question but not getting why it's giving error. 
Please help me in getting this very simple prog work. It's giving error and seg fault as shown below in comments.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct msgclient
{
    int msglen;
    int msgtype;
    char cp[100];
}M1;

int main()
{
    M1 *m;
    m=malloc(sizeof(M1));
    m->msglen=5;  
    m->msgtype=6; 
    m->cp="hi how are you";  //error

    printf("\n%d\n%d\n%s",m->msglen,m->msgtype,m->cp);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: `M1 m = { 5, 6, "hi how are you"};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for your struct

```
 M1 *m= malloc(sizeof(M1)) ;
```

and use `strncpy` to copy string into array

```
 int n = strlen("hi how are you");
 strncpy(m->cp,"hi how are you",n);
 m->cp[n] = '\0';
```

`m->cp ="hi how are you";` won't compile as you trying to assign address of array `"hi how are you"` to array `cp`, it is like writing `&m->cp[0] = &"hi how are you"[0];`

Comment: thanks it's working.  I was mainly concerned for the string part. It's clear now.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is

```
M1* m;
```

m is not initialised and will point to a random memory address. You need to do

```
M1* m = malloc(sizeof(M1));
...
strncpy(m->cp, "hi how are you", 15);
free(m);
```

Comment: @user3436838 because "hi how are you" is a const char* whereas m->cp is an array.

Answer (score 1):

You must allocate memory for the `m` pointer. In your program the `m` pointer is not initialized, it contains garbage and it points most likely to invalid memory.

For example:

```
M1 *m = malloc(sizeof M1) ;
```

Or just not using a pointer like:

```
M1 m;
m.msglen=5;
m.msgtype=6;
strcpy(m.cp, "hi how are you"); // see also below
```

Other problem:

```
m.cp = "hi how are you" ;
```

or

```
m->cp = "hi how are you" ;
```

wont compile, you need to use the `strcpy` function. There is no real string type in C as it exists in other languages.

Comment: And you cannot assign a string literal to `cp`.